# Type HTMLButtonElement cannot be converted to type T

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm playing with TypeScript code playground with the below code. The code seems to be fine to me but it is giving the error

> "Type HTMLButtonElement cannot be converted to type T"

```
class DomFactory {
    create<T extends HTMLElement>(args): T {
        return document.createElement('button') as T;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of your code? You pass the generic type and then convert the result to this type? You always have a `HTMLButtonElement` returned...

Comment: @smnbbrv I got the mistake. Can you post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the generic type and then convert the result to this type. This is obsolete because the returned type is always `HTMLButtonElement`. So this does not really make sense.

There is one case when you normally still want to have the type being inferred. This happens when you want to create an instance of some class with a factory (thus you don't know the returned type). This is the example from [official docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html):

```
class BeeKeeper {
    hasMask: boolean;
}

class ZooKeeper {
    nametag: string;
}

class Animal {
    numLegs: number;
}

class Bee extends Animal {
    keeper: BeeKeeper;
}

class Lion extends Animal {
    keeper: ZooKeeper;
}

function createInstance<A extends Animal>(c: new () => A): A {
    return new c();
}

createInstance(Lion).keeper.nametag;  // typechecks!
createInstance(Bee).keeper.hasMask;   // typechecks!
```

Here the returned type is the one that is being passed.